# JSON.parse file input differ from parsing string literal

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

Im using nodejs to parse some JSON files and insert them into mongodb,the JSON in these files have invalid JSON characters like \n,\" etc ..
The thing that i dont understand is that if i tried to parse like :

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar\n"}'))
```

i get

```
   undefined:1
  {"foo":"bar
```

but if i tried to parse the input from the file (The file has the same string {"foo":"bar\n"})like:

```
new lazy(fs.createReadStream("info.json"))
    .lines
    .forEach(function(line){    
var line = line.toString(); 
        console.log(JSON.parse(line));
    }
);
```

every thing works fine , i want to know if this fine and its ok to parse the files i have, or i should replace all invalid JSON characters before i parse the files ,
and why is there a difference between the two.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can read `"\n"` if your text file, then it's not an end of line but the `\` character followed by a `n`.

`\n` in a JavaScript string literal adds an end of line and they're forbidden in JSON strings.

See [json.org](http://json.org/) :

[image]

To put an end of line in a JSON string, you must escape it, which means you must escape the `\` in a JavaScript string so that there's "\n" in the string received by `JSON.parse` :

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar\\n"}'))
```

This would produce an object whose foo property value would contain an end of line :

[image]

Comment: I see ,thanks for you
but what if i want the \n in the string literal to be a normal character not a line feed how i write it (\n is invalid and \\n is a line feed)?

Comment: i get it '{"foo":"bar\\\\n"}' :)